# Does IE have an equivalent of keyword bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, bookmarks, keyword

I use Firefox's [keyword bookmarks](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html), is there an equivalent in IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and it's called Quick Search. In the past you could download IE "power toys" to help manage them. Not sure if that is still supported but I found a regedit way on the Drupal site that you can use as a template:

http://drupal.org/node/494308

Comment: Great thanks, note that I tried to use "l" for `I'm Feeling Lucky" but it didn't work, looks like "l" is reserved for *live*, it did work with "gl".

Comment: Great, still works with IE9 !!

Answer (score 1):

I created [Shortmarks](http://shortmarks.com) to let you use a single set of keyword bookmarks from any browser, including IE.  You set Shortmarks as your browser's default custom search engine, then use the keywords as you do in Firefox.

Comment: Nice initiative but not configurable

Comment: You're probably looking at the default set of bookmarks for users who aren't logged in.  Login with a Google account to modify the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but in previous versions you've been able to set a shortcut key to jump to the page.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Hi @HackToHell, please take note of the posting date - I'm pretty sure comments weren't added to StackExchange until 2010!

Comment: @Ross According to [this StackExchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/), comments were implemented in September 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, download [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) and use that to configure them.

If you're running Vista, TweakUI doesn't exist (yet?).  Apparently it's possible to get the XP version running and it will still do what you want.  No guarantees though :-)